custom button in flutter_quill (version ^9.3.18)
In flutter_quill (web implementation), I have a custom button, on its click I call a widget which has form with text field and check box values, upon filling those details,
I want to know how to show those details in flutter_quill controller, with checkbox control and text.
Secondly, how to re-launch this widget when cursor is back on this information or highlight the custom button so that user can click to relaunch and edit.
I am new to flutter and unable to proceed with this.
